# How can the JDialog send the data to the main JFrame using MVC for Java with GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller, model

I am making a Java program with GUI and a sort of database stored in an implementation of the ArrayList but I'm confused as to how the controller can transfer the information from one JDialog to another.

Is there a way to initialize the ArrayList once and to have access with the controllers to that same list? Because for now all I can seem to do would be to initialize a new model in any of the new JDialog that I open.

With that MadProgrammer told me I've progressed with the issue, not I'm stuck at the part where I actually have to read the data gathered by the child JDialog back to the main JFrame. I can create an object that will gather all the information in the JDialog but I can't use it after.

Comment: Wouldn't the controller be required to pass a reference to existing data model when it transferred control?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, can you just really send the model to the second controller?

Comment: Why not?  It will, of course, depend on your requirements, but if the second controller requires an instance of the same model, why not?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, what would it require in order to create an instance of a controller+view without the second view having access to the model?

Comment: The entirely depends on your needs.  Presumably, the second view needs "some kind" of model to model its state...that's kind of the point.

Comment: You could define a singleton of some kind which maintains the central state of the `ArrayList`, but it's all semantics without context.  Do the two controllers know about each other?  How would the `ArrayList` provide notification about changes to it's state?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, for now I have my first controller call the second view which instantiate the second controller, so I don't think they know about each other.. But I'd be really interested in a way to send the model from one to the other.

Comment: Okay, that sounds wrong, the controllers should be capable of talking with each other, the controller should be responsible for creating the view and managing the model and view - IMHO, that's why it's in "control"...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I've managed to send the model over to the child JDialog with the correct controller-view order, but now I can't seem to retrieve the data gained by JDialog, I read enough to know that I can't be using a singleton either.

Comment: Is the dialog (view) updating the model?  Do you have a reference to this model or have some way to gain a reference to this model?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, [edited this answer] I don't know exactly how I'm supposed to do that, I do call the view with a reference from the controller but the view doesn't exactly see the model as it's the controller's job right?. I do have getters for the components in the view if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Yep, and your dialog should be modifying the state of the model (presumably via the controller), which means that modifications should be reflected in all references to the same instance of the model.